# Moving editable items between two lists?

Tags: list, livecode

**Can't post pictures yet let me know if needed**

Thank you for any help! The object of this is to be able to edit a list on one card and move it to a list on another card. I am also trying to have the item moved also include an editable time, an editable description and a picture of the object. All of which is not shown on the list, just the title. if I need to explain more let me know. I'm rather new at this.

```
Card Edit: 
on preopencard   
   ## Populate the fields
   put empty into field "title 2"
   put empty into field "description 2"
   put the long date into field "date 2"

   ## Check which task we want to edit 
   ## using the custom property set on this card when we selected a task from the list
   put the cTaskID2 of me into tTaskID2

   ## Get the current details of the task
   put taskDetail2(tTaskID2, "title 2") into tTitle2
   put taskDetail2(tTaskID2, "description 2") into tDescription2
   put taskDetail2(tTaskID2, "completed 2") into tCompleted2
   ## And display then in the relevant fields
   put tTitle2 into field "title 2"
   put tDescription2 into field "description 2"

   ## Set the label of the completed button to allow you to toggle the state
   if tCompleted2 then
      set the label of button "completed 2" to "mark as incomplete"
   else
      set the label of button "completed 2" to "mark as complete"
   end if
end preopencard

on closeCard
   ## Check which task we want to update 
   ## using the custom property set on this card when we selected a task from the list
   put the cTaskID2 of me into tTaskID2

   if tTaskID2 is not empty then
      ## Update the task data in the cTaskData custom property of the stack
      updateTask2 tTaskID2, field "title 2", field "description 2"

      ## Save the task data out to file, ensures our file always refelects the current state
     saveTaskData
   end if
end closeCard



Stack script: (The ones with 2 are for this card) 


on preOpenStack
   ## Read the task list in from file
   readTaskData
end preOpenStack

on addTask pTitle, pDescription
   ## Add a task to the custom property of the stack that is storing the task list
   ## Remember you cannot update a part of a custom property
   ## It must be set in its entirety

  put the cTaskData of me into tTaskDetails
  put pTitle & tab & pDescription & tab & "false" & return after tTaskDetails
  set the cTaskData of me to tTaskDetails
end addTask

on addTask2 pTitle2, pDescription2
   ## Add a task to the custom property of the stack that is storing the task list
   ## Remember you cannot update a part of a custom property
   ## It must be set in its entirety

  put the cTaskData2 of me into tTaskDetails2
  put pTitle2 & tab & pDescription2 & tab & "false" & return after tTaskDetails2
  set the cTaskData2 of me to tTaskDetails2
end addTask2

on updateTask pLineNumber, pTitle, pDescription, pCompleted, 
   ## Update the details for  the given task in the custom property of the stack thast is storing the task list

   put the cTaskData of me into tTaskDetails
   set the itemDel to tab

   if pTitle <> empty then put pTitle into item 1 of line pLineNumber of tTaskDetails
   if pDescription <> empty then put pDescription into item 2 of line pLineNumber of tTaskDetails
   if pCompleted <> empty then put pCompleted into item 3 of line pLineNumber of tTaskDetails
   set the cTaskData of me to tTaskDetails
end updateTask

on updateTask2 pLineNumber2, pTitle2, pDescription2, pCompleted2, 
   ## Update the details for  the given task in the custom property of the stack thast is storing the task list

   put the cTaskData2 of me into tTaskDetails2
   set the itemDel to tab

   if pTitle2 <> empty then put pTitle into item 1 of line pLineNumber2 of tTaskDetails2
   if pDescription2 <> empty then put pDescription2 into item 2 of line pLineNumber2 of tTaskDetails2
   if pCompleted2 <> empty then put pCompleted2 into item 3 of line pLineNumber2 of tTaskDetails2
   set the cTaskData2 of me to tTaskDetails2
end updateTask2

on deleteTask pLineNumber
   ## Delete the given task from the custom property of the stack
   ## Remember the task id corresponds to the line number of the task in the custom property
   put the cTaskData of me into tTaskDetails
   delete line pLineNumber of tTaskDetails
   set the cTaskData of me to tTaskDetails
end deleteTask

on deleteTask2 pLineNumber2
   ## Delete the given task from the custom property of the stack
   ## Remember the task id corresponds to the line number of the task in the custom property
   put the cTaskData2 of me into tTaskDetails2
   delete line pLineNumber2 of tTaskDetails2
   set the cTaskData2 of me to tTaskDetails2
end deleteTask2

on deleteAllTasks
   ## Delete all tasks
   set the cTaskData of me to empty
end deleteAllTasks

on deleteAllTasks2
   ## Delete all tasks
   set the cTaskData2 of me to empty
end deleteAllTasks2

function taskDetail pLineNumber, pDetailType
   ## Get the specified detail of the specified task
   ## Remember each line of the custom property represents a task
   ## and the task details are tab separated

  put the cTaskData of me into tTaskDetails
  set the itemDel to tab
  switch pDetailType
    case "title"
      put item 1 of line pLineNumber of tTaskDetails into tDetail
      break
    case "description"
      put item 2 of line pLineNumber of tTaskDetails into tDetail
      break
    case "completed"
      put item 3 of line pLineNumber of tTaskDetails into tDetail
      break
  end switch
  return tDetail
end taskDetail

function taskDetail2 pLineNumber2, pDetailType2
   ## Get the specified detail of the specified task
   ## Remember each line of the custom property represents a task
   ## and the task details are tab separated

  put the cTaskData2 of me into tTaskDetails2
  set the itemDel to tab
  switch pDetailType2
    case "title2"
      put item 1 of line pLineNumber2 of tTaskDetails2 into tDetail2
      break
    case "description2"
      put item 2 of line pLineNumber2 of tTaskDetails2 into tDetail2
      break
    case "completed2"
      put item 3 of line pLineNumber2 of tTaskDetails2 into tDetail2
      break
  end switch
  return tDetail2
end taskDetail2

function taskCount
   ## Find out how many tasks are currently in the list
   return the number of lines in the cTaskData of me
end taskCount

function taskCount2
   ## Find out how many tasks are currently in the list
   return the number of lines in the cTaskData2 of me
end taskCount2

on saveTaskData
   ## Build the path to the file we want to store the data in
   ## In this case we want to use the "documents" folder
   ## Save the task list out to file
   put specialFolderPath("documents") & "/tasklist.txt" into tSavePath
   put the cTaskData of me into url ("file:" & tSavePath)
end saveTaskData

on readTaskData
   ## Read the task list in from file
   put specialFolderPath("documents") & "/tasklist.txt" into tSavePath
   if there is a file tSavePath then
      put url ("file:" & tSavePath) into tTaskDetails
   end if

   ## Set the custom property of the stack to the contents of the file
   set the cTaskData of me to tTaskDetails
end readTaskData



List on card:

on mouseUp
   ## Work out which task has been selected
   ## The taskID corresponds to the line number in the list
   put word 2 of the clickline into tTaskID2
   showTaskDetails2 tTaskID2
end mouseUp

on showTaskDetails2 tTaskID2
   ## Set a custom property on the task editor card
   ## This tells it which task has been selected so the correct details can be shown
   set the cTaskID2 of card "edit 2" to tTaskID2
   go to card "edit 2"
end showTaskDetails2
```

This is Livecode

Comment: Could you explain what kind of picture you want to move from where to where exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear to me why you save that much data in properties. Once data is in a field, you can just keep it there. When you need to move data from a field on one card to a field in another card, you can do so directly. For example, let's assume that you want to copy the contents of fields "Title" and "Description" of card 1 to the same fields on card 2.

```
// this handler is in the card script of card 2
on preOpenCard
  put fld "Title" of cd 1 into fld "Title"
  put fld "Description" of cd 1 into fld "Description"
end preOpenCard
```

This is all you need. There is no need for custom properties in this particularly case.

Comment: Ok i get when you say **When you need to move data from a field on one card to a field in another card, you can do so directly.** but is there a way i can have hidden text that doesn't display on the list, but displays on the edit card? Im confused with understanding the relationships between handlers. But anyways, I want to have a list of different items with the title displayed on the list, with other text and a picture hidden while connected to the title, but on a separate card the hidden text and picture populates the appropriate fields and can be edited.

Comment: That's a very long sentence, @SirDerp. Can you describe step by step what you want? You can change your question and add the steps. You can copy data from hidden fields on one card to visible fields to another card, in the same way as shown in the handler in my answer. For relationships between controls, cards, stacks and handlers, you might want to ask a new question.

Comment: is there a way i can send you picture of the app? its skinned right now but i need to get the code to work. it would help in understanding the flow of the app.

Comment: You could put a picture of the app in the question. If you want real support, it shouldn't be too difficult to find my contact data. I believe I shouldn't put my e-mail address on SO :-)

Comment: Heres my email sirderpso@gmail.com

Comment: i sent an email to economyxtalk and got a weird response. if you can email me at sirderpso@gmail.com and email me back that's be very helpfull